# How to iterate over items in returned k8s client object?

Tags: python, kubernetes, namespaces, client

am using python 3 and k8s client to query for various cluster info.

In some cases, instead of a well formed json object, the client is returning a custom object that I can't figure out how to 'read'.

As a specific example, I am using the k8s client method: list_persistent_volume_claim_for_all_namespaces()

This returns instances of type V1PersistentVolumeClaim as described here: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PersistentVolumeClaim.md

My problem is how can I process these instances and extract the contained information?  I would like to iterate over the contents as I would any Json object, but that doesn't work.  I can reference it as a string, but, it is very dirty with quoting issues, unquoted values, unquoted numbers, embedded line feeds, etc.  I have been able to clean it up with a bunch of regex subs, but, it is a nightmare and I never know when some other piece of data may show up and break it.  Is there a better way to extract this information?  Or a link to doc on how to parse the results being returned would be great...  What am I missing here?

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Do you have a more complete code example?  I'd expect a client call like that to give you back instances of that object; you shouldn't directly see the JSON at all.

Comment: Thanks @David Maze, it 'looked' like JSON to me, but was really a yaml string (sort of).  I say 'sort of' because in the data, it it had the string 'datetime.datetime(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, ss, tz....)'.  Note: all datetime numbers were populated.  Plus there was a bad string of the form "...' \n '..." (ie., a crlf embedded between to single quoted strings with no comma).  Apparently yaml.safe_load could not handle those 2 situations.  Once I cleaned them up, I was able to do a yaml.safe_load and convert to a dict and process in python.

Answer (score 0):

Duuuhhh...  haven't done much with yaml yet.  esp. raw yaml strings like this.  yaml.safe_load(str) converts it to a dict...  handy...